# Python (DataQuest): Confused about declaring lists outside vs. inside loops?

Tags: python

New to Python and learning through DataQuest. I'm learning a bit about creating a list of lists (would plural be lists of lists or list of listes? :P). Well, for this particular section, this was the correct code:

```
numerical_list = [];

for line in nested_list:
    name = line[0]
    count= float(line[1])
    new_list = [name, count]
    numerical_list.append(new_list)
print(numerical_list[0:5]);
```

They give you a little bit of instruction, including creating the empty numerical_list before starting the loop, but I'm slightly confused as to why I need to declare that empty list while, in the body of the loop, I was able to create

```
new_list = [name, count]
```

Without declaring it outside. I THINK I get it, but I want to be sure.

My understanding is that, because numerical_list is empty, it needs to be declared outside of the loop so that it exists and then, on the line

```
numerical_list.append(new_list)
```

I'm breathing life into it. Meanwhile, because I'm declaring new_list with arguments, it already has that "life" (I'm sure there's a better, more technical word for it but I don't know it) and doesn't need to be established separately. Is that correct? Or am I going totally crazy here and making up logic as I go?

In other words, is this correct: new, empty lists cannot be created inside a loop but new lists with arguments can.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can also create empty lists inside loops. For example, you could rewrite the list creation inside the loop to

```
new_list = []
new_list.append(name)
new_list.append(count)
```

However, the loop is there to populate `numerical_list`, so it needs to be created before the loop. If you created it inside the loop it will be overwritten with an empty list in every iteration.

Comment: That makes sense, and since new_list has arguments, it's just being overwritten by the same argument and therefore not changing anything, right?